# Problemas com valores passados para variaveis static com class no servidor

Tags: c#, asp.net, variáveis

Bom dia pessoal.

Estou sofrendo atualmente com um problema e não consigo encontrar a solução.
Tenho um sistema de login em ASP.NET C# quando faço a autenticação tudo ocorre corretamente só que ai que está o problema eu preciso pegar o valor de ID do meu banco de dados partir do usuário que foi autenticado ali pela aquela vez até que o método que utilizo funciona, eu repasso o valor do ID capturado no momento do login para uma variável public static em uma class e ele me redireciona para a tela de inicio que é o correto com o valor na variável.. e ai o problema acontece, essa variável não guarda o valor para o computador do cliente e sim no servidor então quando alguém faz o Login no site todas as pessoas que acessarem este site estará logada automaticamente neste login tudo isso por conta da variável static na class alguém sabe como resolvo está situação que está em comendo o juízo.

Agradeço desde de já!! Kennedy

Na minha class Global

```
                 public static int Cod_Login;
```

minha validação de login

```
                DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                DS = ValidaLogin(TxtUsuario.Text, TxtSenha.Text);
                for (int i = 0; i < DS.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                 {
                 Cod_User = Convert.ToInt32(DS.Tables[0].Rows[i][0] == DBNull.Value ? 0 :                                         DS.Tables[0].Rows[i][0]);
                }

                if (Cod_User != 0)
                {
                    Class_Global.Cod_Login = Cod_User; //aonde passo o valor para a variavel
                    Response.Redirect("/Default.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    LblMsg.Text = "CPF e/ou Senha incorretos.";
                    LblMsg.Visible = true;
                }
```

Na minha pagina de inicio apos o login

```
                if (Class_Global.Cod_Login != 0)
                                {

                //aqui utilizo se o meu código caso for o valor diferente de zero

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complementando a resposta do [@CarlosAlmeida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/87723/carlos-almeida), pode guardar o valor em sessão, mas caso pretenda manter a página "viva" durante mais do que 20 minutos, deve definir o `timeout` da sessão no seu `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Desta forma os valores em sessão ficam armazenados em memória durante **60 minutos**.

Comment: irei testar pra manter ela viva

Comment: Eu não sabia dessa obrigado pela ajuda foi muito útil, o meu problema era que a session se perdia quando eu atualizava a pagina...

Answer (score 0):

Presumo que esteja a usar Web Form.
Se eu entendi o problema, acho que a resolução seja passar passar por variàveis de sessão.

```
Session("ID_USER") = valor;
```

Comment: Eu fiz isso funcionou, mas do nada incrivelmente a session perde o valor...

Comment: utilizei novamente a session com a dica do amigo abaixo e conseguir manter a session obrigado a vocês...

Comment: Acrescenta no ficheiro Global_asax.vb na Session_start a seguinte linha. Session.Timeout = 1500